# label points in GPA plot

Tags: r

I am using the function GPA in the R package "FactoMineR" on sensory data, a method called Free Choice Profiling. The GPA function performs a general procrustes analysis on the data, afterwards I am able to plot the results with the function plotGPA from the same package.

My question: Is it possible to label the points of the scatterplot made using the plotGPA function? It does not seem to be an option in this function as standard.

XLstat in excel has this option, but I would like to do it in R as well.

my data:
https://ufile.io/l6i19

my code:

```
   library(FactoMineR)

blomkaal <- as.data.frame(read.csv(file="blomkaal.csv",sep=";",row.names=1,header = TRUE))

c.blomkaal <- apply(blomkaal, 2, gsub, patt=",", replace=".")
c.blomkaal <- as.data.frame(c.blomkaal,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1:60){
c.blomkaal[,i] <- as.numeric(c.blomkaal[,i])
}

blomkaal.gpa <- GPA(c.blomkaal, group=c(6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6),name.group = c("Chris","Torben","Mie","Lone N","Aase","Annemette","Lone" ,"Iben","Lena","Ines"))

plot.GPA(blomkaal.gpa)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I have now added the code and my data